# switch statement only incrementing once

Tags: java, android, button, switch-statement, increment

I am creating a coffee ordering app for school. My intent for the code below is to increment or decrement the coffee integer based on whether the subtractCoffeeButton or addCoffeeButton is clicked.  coffeeTV is used to show the user the number of coffee's queued to be ordered. subtotal and subtotalTV are used to hold the price and display it to the user.

As it is, the subtractCoffee and addCoffee buttons work to increment coffee and coffeeTV from 0 to 1 and vise-versa, subtotal and subtotalTV also work for displaying 0.00 and 2.5, but it won't increment any further than that. Further button clicks result in nothing happening when it is expected to increment coffee to 2,3,4,etc. and subtotal to 5.00,7.50,10.00,etc.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_relative);

        Button subtractCoffee = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subtractCoffeeButton);
        subtractCoffee.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button addCoffee = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addCoffeeButton);
        addCoffee.setOnClickListener(this);

}



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    double subtotal = 0.00;

    int coffee = 0;


    double coffeePrice = 2.50;

    TextView coffeeTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCoffeeOrder);
    String coffeeString = coffeeTV.getText().toString();
    int coffeeTracker = Integer.parseInt(coffeeString);

    TextView subTotalTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSubtotalCost);


    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.subtractCoffeeButton:
            if (coffeeTracker == 0) {
                break;
            } else if (coffeeTracker == 1) {
                coffee = 0;
                coffeeTracker = 0;
                coffeeTV.setText(Integer.toString(coffee));
                break;
            } else {
                coffee = coffee - 1;
                coffeeTV.setText(Integer.toString(coffee));
                subtotal = subtotal - coffeePrice;
                subTotalTV.setText(Double.toString(subtotal));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.addCoffeeButton:
            coffee += 1;
            coffeeTracker+=1;
            coffeeTV.setText(Integer.toString(coffee));
            subtotal = subtotal + coffeePrice;
            subTotalTV.setText(Double.toString(subtotal));
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Because every time `onclick` is called, `int coffee = 0` set coffee to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
double subtotal = 0.00;
int coffee = 0;
double coffeePrice = 2.50;
```

These variables have to be outside the onClick method.
Everytime you call onClick they get initiated again with 0.

Answer (score 2):

because

```
double subtotal = 0.00;
int coffee = 0;
double coffeePrice = 2.50;
```

are in the local scope of your method. Declare as member variable and their value will persist as long as the current Activity is not destroyed

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have

```
double subtotal = 0.00;
int coffee = 0;
```

at the beginning of your onClick() function. Thus, every time you click a button, you reset the number to 0 and then increment it to 1.

Besides, I'd recommend you to define separate OnClickListener instead of a global one. Something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager;

    EditText mainEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            ActivityManager.TaskDescription taskDescription =
                    new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(null, null, getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryDark));
            setTaskDescription(taskDescription);
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary));
        }

        appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor = preferences.edit();
        String savedText = preferences.getString("mainText", "");

        mainEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mainEditText);
        mainEditText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollAndSelectMovingMethod());
        mainEditText.getText().append(savedText);
        Selection.setSelection(mainEditText.getText(), savedText.length());

        mainEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(mainEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            }
        });

        mainEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                onEditTextTextChanged(charSequence.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }

    private void onEditTextTextChanged(String text) {
        saveText(text);
        updateWidget();
    }

    private void saveText(String text) {
        editor.putString("mainText", text);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void updateWidget() {
        int[] ids = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(this, Widget.class));
        for (int id : ids)
            Widget.updateAppWidget(appWidgetManager, id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you go with the other answers approach (field variables) or you read and parse the amounts on each `onClick()`. In code it would look something like:

```
static final double COFFEE_PRICE = 2.50;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView coffeeTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCoffeeOrder);
    String coffeeString = coffeeTV.getText().toString();
    int coffee = Integer.parseInt(coffeeString);

    TextView subtotalTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSubtotalCost);
    String subtotalString = subtotalTV.getText().toString();
    double subtotal = Double.parseDouble(subtotalString);

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.subtractCoffeeButton:
            if (coffee == 0) {
                break;
            }
            coffee--;
            subtotal -= COFFEE_PRICE;
            coffeeTV.setText(Integer.toString(coffee));
            subtotalTV.setText(Double.toString(subtotal));
            break;
        case R.id.addCoffeeButton:
            coffee++;
            subtotal += COFFEE_PRICE;
            coffeeTV.setText(Integer.toString(coffee));
            subtotalTV.setText(Double.toString(subtotal));         
            break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already said subtotal, coffe and coffePrice need to be outside of the onClick function. Also coffeTracker should always be the same as coffe as far as I can see, so you dont need the variable

This should be your code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        double subtotal = 0.00;
        int coffee = 0;
        double coffeePrice = 2.50;    

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_relative);

            Button subtractCoffee = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subtractCoffeeButton);
            subtractCoffee.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button addCoffee = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addCoffeeButton);
            addCoffee.setOnClickListener(this);

    }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        TextView coffeeTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCoffeeOrder);
        TextView subTotalTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSubtotalCost);


        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.subtractCoffeeButton:
                if (coffee == 0) {
                    break;
                } else if (coffee == 1) {
                    coffee = 0;
                    coffeeTV.setText(Integer.toString(coffee));
                    break;
                } else {
                    coffee = coffee - 1;
                    coffeeTV.setText(Integer.toString(coffee));
                    subtotal = subtotal - coffeePrice;
                    subTotalTV.setText(Double.toString(subtotal));
                }
                break;
            case R.id.addCoffeeButton:
                coffee += 1;
                coffeeTV.setText(Integer.toString(coffee));
                subtotal = subtotal + coffeePrice;
                subTotalTV.setText(Double.toString(subtotal));
                break;
        }

    }
```